# Is the list of Apps on my iphone available for reuse in a different display?

Tags: iphone

I have an idea to use the apps on my iphone as a list for a different way to launch the program. But I have no idea if I can see the apps in something I can display? Is this possible? If it is possible, can I launch the listed app from my app? What do I need to access to get this done?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way using the official SDK to enumerate the list of applications the user has installed.

Unofficially, with a jailbroken phone you can check the contents of the applications folder.

Answer (score 1):

It is true there is no specific way to do this with the normal SDK. However if specific apps you had used URL schemes you can invoke them programatically. Google maps, mail, safari, sms have it. Any application can choose to implement their own custom one. This obviously doesn't help with any random app but if you have specific apps your targeting you might be able to integrate that way.